# Permutations, arrangements with some elements always together.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The question is, find all the arrangements of the the word 'EAMCOT' such that no two vowels come together. I understand the approach to it with setting up the consonants as separators and that gives the answer 144.
However, I tried doing this differently. Total number of arrangements is 6!. Then taking those in which 2 or 3 vowels definitely occur together. We take the 3 vowels two and a time, fix those as a single element, which gives 5! as the number of such arrangements. For three vowels, I see $2\cdot 3$ ways in which we group two vowels together, with order being important. But that gives total of such ways in which vowels do occur together as $2\cdot 3\cdot 5!$ which is just $6!$, equal to the number of overall total arrangements and patently untrue. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Every time you count arrangements with two vowels together the way you did, it also counts and in fact _overcounts_ arrangements with all $3$ vowels together. Please apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply the [principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). You substract your result $2⋅3⋅5!=6!$ from $6!$, the total arrangements, and then you should add the overcounted cases that is when ALL the $3$ vowels are together which yields $3!\cdot 4!=144$.

Comment: @Aniruddh Any further doubt?